# Make a parameter in minimal API as an optional in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

I have this API as you can see:

```
app.MapGet("/api/fund/{fundCode}", ([FromServices] IMediator mediator,string fundCode)
    => mediator.Send(new GetFundsQuery(fundCode)));
```

I want to set `fundcode` as an optional parameter to my API, so I changed it to

```
app.MapGet("/api/fund/{fundCode?}", ([FromServices] IMediator mediator,string fundCode)
    => mediator.Send(new GetFundsQuery(fundCode)));
```

But it didn't work, and when I call this address

```
https://localhost:7147/api/fund
```

I get an http 404 error. Why?

Comment: I failed to find an explanation from the official document, but could you pls take a try with `string? fundCode`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I used code below, I'll get "null" as a response when I call `localhost:port/hello`. But when I use `string id` as the parameter, I got 400 bad request...

```
app.MapGet("/hello/{id?}", (string? id) =>
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return "null";
    }
    else {
        return id;
    }

});
```

I also tried to use code below and when I call `localhost:port/hello`, I get "empty" as the response.

```
app.MapGet("/hello/{id?}", (string? id) =>
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return "null";
    }
    else {
        return id;
    }

});

app.MapGet("/hello", () =>
{
     return "empty";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the query parameter. For example:

```
app.MapGet("/api/fund", GetFundsAsync).Produces<IList<Fund>>();

private async Task<IList> GetFundsAsync(IMediator mediator,string fundCode = null)
{
    return await mediator.Send(new GetFundsQuery(fundCode));
}
```

This way `https://localhost:7147/api/fund` will return results
And `https://localhost:7147/api/fund?fundCode=ABC` will work too